# Compressing using pixz without losing primary file

Tags: algorithm, compression

Is there a way or option to compress an archive *.tar using pixz algorithm without losing that primary *.tar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line, compress your file the same, but pass the `--keep` flag to `xz`:

```
# tar cf my_archive.tar my_directory
# xz --keep my_archive.tar
```

Comment: So there is a solutions,thank you very much Kingsley :D !

Answer (score 0):

Use pixz, you can just do `pixz < input > output.pxz`. Tada!